# Rails Paperclip images not showing in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

My images attached with Paperclip, are showing up ok in development environment but in production they are showing up broken, I've checked ant the url for the images is the same in both:

```
<img alt="Badminton" class="img-rounded" src="/system/sports/images/000/000/012/small/badminton.jpg?1365944689" />
```

I'm using Paperclip 3.0.4 and using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production, what I'm doing wrong?

Ok, I've checked again and I'm not getting the same url for the images in development than in production.
In development my image is:

```
src="/system/sports/images/000/000/012/small/badminton.jpg?1365944689"
```

And in production is:

```
src="/system/sports/images/000/000/012/small/badminton.jpg?1366328860"
```

In production if I try to access the image with the development url it shows up properly.

What is going on here? why is changing the number at the end of the images url from development to production?

Comment: Maybe a permission problem in production?

Comment: I'm running it in local, and can access properly the images from production using the image url from development, check my edit please

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same url!  That number on the end is not part of the image path, its used for caching...ignore it (in regard to this question).

Your production url is looking for an image on your system.  That cant be.

Who is your host?  Many hosts (Heroku included, if thats who your using) do not offer the ability to upload image assets.  You must use a separate service, like Amazon S3 storage.  Its easy and cheap.

Comment: But I'm running it in my mac not in a hosting, and in production if I try to access the image changing the number at the end for the number of the same image in development it works, so what I have to do to have this working in production?. And thanks for the advice on the host thing I was thinking to deploy it to Heroku now I'm rethinking about it.

Comment: Your mac is local...development only.  It's not your production environment.  Why are you trying to play in your production environment locally?  The reason the image loads when you change the number at the end of the url is because your browser is probably grabbing the local cached version of that image from the last time you loaded it.  
The image is found via its path, which is easily managed for you by the asset pipeline and simply using the image_url or image_path helpers that rails gives you.
Also, Heroku is great.  IMO the only real option for a rails app.  Just use S3 in production.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Rails 4.2.4. By default , Rails will not read the folder *public* .
This information is present on `config/environments/production.rb`.
Because  Apache or NGINX already handles this.

To solve that you can change that line `config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` , To

`config.serve_static_files = true`. If you are using previous version rails , it may be written as `config.serve_static_assets = true`

Comment: Same in Rails 5.1.3. Thanks a lot for the answer!